# How to save edits on a custom visual force page on a related object

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I have a visual force page where the standard controller is the Case object and it has a related object. I need to save edits made to the related object, but there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way of doing so.

Code:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Case.Vitality_Check_Attributes__r}" var="att">
      <table>
            <td class="text-right">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name" for="name"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!att.name}" id="name"/>
                <br></br>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Assesment Group ID" for="agi"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!att.Assessment_Group_ID__c}" id="agi"/>
                <br></br>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Assesment Identifier" for="ai"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!att.Assessment_Identifier__c}" id="ai"/>
                <br></br>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Assesment ID" for="aid"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!att.Attribute_ID__c}" id="aid"/>
                <br></br>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Attribute Identifier" for="ati"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!att.Attribute_Identifier__c}" id="ati"/>
                <br></br>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Attribute" for="atr"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!att.Attribute_Value__c}" id="atr"/>
                <br></br>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Source Type" for="src"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!att.Source_Type__c}" id="src"/>
                <br></br>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!att.Save}" value="Save"/>
            </td>
       </table>
</apex:repeat>
```

How would I make the att.save work?

Comment: Is this VF page associated to a `Case` controllerExtension class?  If yes,  then you want to upsert all of the rows in the table in one action, not have a save button on each row

Answer (score -1):

Use an Apex controller extension class and refer it in the extensions attribute of the page tag. Create a method called save and then refer to the save method as {!save} in the action attribute of the visualforce tag. The save method contains the Apex code to save the Case and ita related record to the relevant objects.